# How to divide a big (64-bit) number by two in PC-Spim

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, mips, divide

I have a school assignment, to find out the sum of 1 + 2 + ... + n in MIPS assembly language (using PC-Spim as a virtual machine). I wrote a simple program which doesn't deal with big numbers (so `n*(n+1)` must not be greater than 2<sup>32</sup>-1 for it to work). I heard today that the professor, if you didn't use registers `hi` and `lo`, will tell you to use them and make the program work for 64-bit numbers too!

So this is the initial program:

```
.data
 n:.word 10
 s:.word 0
.text
main:
 lw $t0,n
 add $t1,$t0,1
 mulou $t1, $t0, $t1
 sra $t1,$t1,1
 sw $t1,s
sfarsit:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

and this is my try to modify it:

```
.data
 n:.word 1048576
 s:.word 0
 s2:.word 0
.text
main:
 lw $t0,n
 add $t1,$t0,1
 mult $t0, $t1
 mflo $t0
 mfhi $t1
 sra $t0,$t0,1
 sra $t1,$t1,1
 sw $t0,s
 sw $t1,s
sfarsit:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

the `sra` trick doesn't work if you apply it to each 32-bit part of your result. (even though I hoped it will lol)

```
n: 1048576
expected result: 549756338176
what the program gives you: 549755813888
```

[image: a program result]

What could I do to divide the big number by two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dividing two 32-bit numbers by 2 separately, not a single 64-bit number by 2.

```
mult $t0, $t1
mflo $t0
mfhi $t1
sra $t0,$t0,1  # $t0 = $t0 >> 1
sra $t1,$t1,1  # $t1 = $t1 >> 1
sw $t0,s
sw $t1,s
```

You need to shift the *whole* 64-bit values. That means the shifted out bit of the higher part must be shifted into the low part

```
sll $t2, $t1, 31   # Backup the bit that will be shifted-out
srl $t2, $t1, 1    # High part: $t1 = $t1 >> 1
srl $t0, $t0, 1    # Low part:  $t0 = $t0 >> 1
or  $t0, $t2, $t0  # Merge the shifted-out bit back
```

Since n is always positive, you don't need to shift arithmetically anyway. Use it as an unsigned type with `srl` instead. In fact if n is a signed type then n/2 is much more complex because you need to do some rounding at the end, since right shift rounds downwards. You can see some demo on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:13),source:'%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0Aint64_t+div2(int64_t+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+x/2%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Auint64_t+div2u(uint64_t+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+x/2%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: If you're ok with an arithmetic right shift (rounding toward -Inf), you can do that by using `sra` on the high half, everything else the same.  The low half is of course unsigned: it doesn't contain the sign bit.  (And you want to shift in a zero to make room to OR in the previous low bit of the high half).  The algorithm for `n/2` is extra clunky on MIPS because it doesn't have add-with-carry (or flags at all) so that requires `sltu` + addu and is harder to grok than on x86 for example.

Comment: Anyway, worth pointing out that `sra` on the low half definitely never makes sense.